# How can I disaggregate date ranges across 2 date columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a multi-dimensional data set in pandas, which has two date columns, one column for the start date and the other for the end date. These columns are rounded on the month, and I need to disaggregate where the range between start and end date exceeds 1 month, and divide the numerical value associated with the date range, evenly across the disaggregated date ranges.

Note that this is a simplified example of the data I am working with. The reason the same start date occurs with different tonnage values is that in practice these activity records occur at different locations, and have other attributes that differ.

For example, given the following pandas code:

```
import pandas as pd
start_dates = ['2015-01-01',
              '2015-01-01',
              '2015-02-01',
              '2015-03-01',
              '2015-04-01']
end_dates = ['2015-02-01',
            '2015-03-01',
            '2015-04-01',
            '2015-07-01',
            '2015-12-01']
df = pd.DataFrame({'start_dates': map(pd.to_datetime, start_dates),
               'end_dates': map(pd.to_datetime, end_dates),
               'tonnage': [1000.0, 3500.0, 2000.0, 3000.0,4000.0]
              })
```

How would I disaggregate into monthly buckets on start and end date spans in order to produce this data frame:

```
end_dates   start_dates tonnage
0   2015-02-01  2015-01-01  1000
1   2015-02-01  2015-01-01  1750
2   2015-03-01  2015-02-01  1750
3   2015-03-01  2015-02-01  1000
4   2015-04-01  2015-03-01  1000
5   2015-04-01  2015-03-01  750
6   2015-05-01  2015-04-01  750
7   2015-06-01  2015-05-01  750
8   2015-07-01  2015-06-01  750
9   2015-05-01  2015-04-01  500
10  2015-06-01  2015-05-01  500
11  2015-07-01  2015-06-01  500
12  2015-08-01  2015-07-01  500
13  2015-09-01  2015-08-01  500
14  2015-10-01  2015-09-01  500
15  2015-11-01  2015-10-01  500
16  2015-12-01  2015-11-01  500
```

Comment: Why do the two first rows in your desired output have the same dates yet different tonnage?

Comment: This is a simplified example of the data I am dealing with. The actual data set also has location related columns, and many other dimensions.

Comment: I understand, but could you give the exact output you're expecting from the example you gave?